# JQuery UI Button : How to set the icon with generated javascript svg?

Tags: jquery-ui, svg, raphael

I just want to know if it is possible to generate a javascript svg and set it as an icon of a jquery ui button.

```
$( "#staveSVG" ).button({
        text: false,
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-document"
        }
});
```

instead "ui-icon-document" can i include an svg there?? I dont mean a svg picture but a generated svg (raphaeljs for example).

Thank you.